# statusCode=unknown status code=9000 | Google Places API for Android

Tags: api, autocomplete, key, google-places-api, sha1

I am using the exact design example google place
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete

I added an api key with the package name and my SHA1 to generate the key
when I run the project via Android Studio on emulators Android works perfectly research.

I generate an apk and install on my device or BlueStacks I get this error **statusCode=unknown status code=9000**

Could someone tell me why this error only on my devices?

Comment: Sorry you're experiencing this issue!

A few questions to try to narrow down the problem:
1. What does your Android manifest look like?
2. Which version of Google Play Services is installed on your devices?

Comment: thank you for answer, my manifest file is exactly this
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceComplete/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: only changed android: value = "ADD_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
and added a credential for the api key and the console google api google to google maps "Android places Api for Android" is enabled and Api for mobile devices
"Google Places API for Android" is also activated. in android emulator works perfectly.

Comment: added android.permission.INTERNET to see if more help did not help. my android device is a 4.1.2 and Google Play Services is the last provided I come to also receive the error statuscode: 9008. I do not know what the problem really is the previous version of the android 5.0?

Comment: Strange indeed! Are you using the exact same APK on your emulator and on your device? If it's a signed APK, then you need to generate the SHA1 for the release certificate (like you did for the debug certificate already) and associate it with your existing API key (see https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup#find-cert). Also double check that the package name is not overridden by Gradle.